# image displayed properly in google chrome not in firefox thru php?

Tags: php, mysql, html, firefox, google-chrome

My php code fetches image url's from the database and this is used to produce image tags dynamically to display image.

This code works fine with google chrome but images are not displayed in firefox...?

code is as shown below:

```
$str="";
$sql="....some query to fetch image urls from data base.....";
$res=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

$str=$str.'<div class="abc"><a href="#"><img src="'.$row['Image_Url'].'" alt="cannot
        display" width="100" height="100" /></a>
  <span class="xyz">'.$row['Image_Name'].'</span></div>';
}
print $str;
```

Comment: Use View Source in both browsers and compare them.

Comment: It'd be more useful if you posted the generated HTML.  If it's a cross browser problem, the issue is most likely *not* with your server-side code

Answer (score 0):

could you post your result page?  mostly this is not server side code problem. you can fix the issue by viewing source of result page. I am also faced this issue, but i found the problem by viewing pagesource of result page. The tags were placed wrongly in result page. You check pagesource of result page.